# How to use T to tranlate strings in web2py module?

Tags: translation, web2py, web2py-modules

I have a countries.py module living in my web2py applications module folder.  It defines the following tuple:

```
COUNTRIES = (
    ('AF', T('Afghanistan')), 
    ('AX', T('Aland Islands')), 
    ('AL', T('Albania')), 
    ('DZ', T('Algeria')), 
    ('AS', T('American Samoa')), 
    ('AD', T('Andorra')), 
    ('AO', T('Angola')), 
    ('AI', T('Anguilla')), 
    ...
```

Which can be use to create country drop down list.  The problem I have is I get an error:

`<type 'exceptions.NameError'> name 'T' is not defined`

So how can I use the translator `T` from a web2py module?

Answer (score 4):

Based on this post in the google group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/cHSKbhbcSSA

I added

```
from gluon import current
T = current.T
```

to the top of my countries.py module and it seems to be working now.